# HTML Table Paste multiple cells

Tags: javascript, html, razor-pages

How can I paste into an HTML table using contentEditable values on multiple cells?

If I try to select them using ctrl+click and paste there nothing happens.

I also found another issue that I can't select cells which aren't side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported natively.

When you paste table values from e.g. Google Sheets, you get a string with horizontal values separated by a TAB character, with a newline character representing the end of a row.

e.g. table values like this:

```
AAA   BBB  CCC
DDD   EEE  FFF
```

would produce the string:

```
AAA\tBBB\tCCC\nDDD\tEEE\tFFF\n
```

You would have to write some Javascript code to process the input characters and insert them into a TD element.